# Froala Editor - Converting image to base64 and sending email using nodemailer. For bigger images it is not working

Tags: node.js, angular7, froala

we have a licensed version of froala. And we are trying to send the editor content as RTF mail.

Right now there is no option to get the content as RTF. Froala is giving it as HTML.

So we are using image.beforeUpload method and converting the image to base64 and sending the content to email.

For small size images it is converting and working fine. But If I convert a bigger image the base64 is very big, So the image is not showing in the email.

Can you provide any solution for the problem? How can I send images and videos embedded inside the froala editor to mail?

Is there any option to retrieve the content as RTF from froala itself.